# How to setup Square PHP SDK in your localhost ( virtual environment )

Tags: php, square

I'm trying to implement Square Payment on my website, however it's not working if I'm using virtual environment(square.dev.local)

Error: applicationid and/or locationid is incorrect

I am using XAMPP, and it's perfectly working if I manually move to the path (localhost/square/).  square sdk

I tried switching environment from SANDBOX to PRODUCTION and CUSTOM. It doesn't work only in virtualhost local.

Answer (score 0):

When you switched to production did you change the URL to the JS library to `https://web.squarecdn.com/v1/square.js` as well as `location_id` and `application_id`?

Comment: Yes, I did. this script works fine when I directly go to the path localhost/path.../ (It doesn't matter if it's production or sandbox mode as long as you use the credentials matched to it's mode, it will work in localhost) but it's not working when it was in virtual environment. I can't add square payment on my website in localhost virtual hosting..

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? With Square’s APIs, HTTPS is required for all API calls to Square endpoints. Unencrypted HTTP API calls do not work.